# Sidebar Conditional Rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a basic app, and the homepage of the app (/) contains a login screen. I have a sidebar component on the app and I do not want to display the sidebar on the login screen. To implement this, I have followed this approach in my App.js:

```
   function App() {
  let url = useLocation();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {url.pathname != "/" ? (
          <Sidebar visible={visible} onHide={() => setVisible(false)}>
            Content
          </Sidebar>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
```

I do not know if there is a better way to implement this  and however, I am not able to implement this method successfully in this App.js. This works fine in other components, but just not in App.js. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined
```

Comment: You can use `{url.pathname != "/" && <Sidebar visible={visible} onHide={() => setVisible(false)}>
            Content
          </Sidebar>}`

Comment: How are you importing your context provider?

Comment: useContext(...) is undefined, is due to reason, your App component is not wrapped in ContextProvider.
In whatever component, you are using useContext, make sure  that component should be wrapped under ContextProvider